# Do x86 processors transmit/receive data in little endian format over USB?

Tags: x86, embedded, serial-port, usb

I'm writing a asynchronous communication controller for a Xilinx FPGA, and I'd like to save myself the trouble of figuring what order x86 processors send data.

On host side, I'm using a C program that uses the following tutorial: http://slackware.osuosl.org/slackware-3.3/docs/mini/Serial-Port-Programming

Also, is it possible to switch the format between big and little endian when sending data?

Comment: USB is a serial bus, least significant bit of every field in a frame is sent first.  What meaning you give to the (up-to) 8192 bits in the data field is entirely up to you.

Comment: @HansPassant I already have a module that reads one byte at a time. I guess what I'm really asking is if I send an integer, in what order will the bytes by read?

Comment: At the CPU level, there's no such thing as bit order.  Bytes are transmitted in parallel, meaning all bits of a byte will be read effectively simultaneously.  There needs to be something in between the CPU and the device to assemble bits into bytes and vice versa.

Comment: not determined by host or architecture.  some portions of the packet/payload are determined by the protocol and are what they are, endians dont matter.  Beyond that if there is a payload then it is whatever you choose to put in there.  If you have done your system engineering then it is also non-endian, the payload layout is defined and both sides simply conform to that payload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB is little-endian.

But if you are talking about sending bytes over a USB serial port, then it depends entirely on the order that the program sends them.

On an Intel system, unless it was originally intended to speak to a big-endian system, I'd expect (but want to verify) them to be sent least-significant byte first.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about asynchronous communications -- serial ports -- then byte order is dependent on the protocol you're running over that serial port.  The x86 is little-endian, so a program sending the bytes of an integer would send the LSB first.

Since you would typically be using some sort of protocol to send data, you'll want to use that protocol's byte order.

So your answer depends on what the x86 program sending data to you is actually going to use.

Answer (score 3):

For serial communications protocols, the endianness is defined by the protocol, not the processor.  USB is little-endian.  See section 7.1 of the USB 3.0 Specification [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/).

The fact that you have an x86 is irrelevant.  A serial communications driver running on the x86 could be written to conform to either a little or big endian protocol.